# Make slider counter, count just the amount of slides in the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, counter

I made a jQuery slider for a website, it has 9 slides, and I want the counter to count JUST until 9. What happens is that as soon as I get to the last slide (09 of 09) and CLICK on the NEXT bnt, it goes to the first slide (01 of 09) and when I click to go to the second slide I get this: 11 of 09. Please help!

It's an infinite slider, and would like the counter to work "UP" and "DOWN", meaning to have the counter add if the user goes NEXT and subtract if the user goes previous.

The slider is in this site http://madebymorro.com/web_dev_vavilco/
at the very bottom.

Thanks!

the code I have is HTML:

```
<section id="construction">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="home-slider">
    <div id="slider-data">
      <div class="count">
        <span class="current">1</span>/09
      </div>
      <div class="slider-nav">
        <div class="prev"><img src="images/home-prev.svg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="next"><img src="images/home-next.svg" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home-slider-c">
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider001.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>zaragoza</p>
          <p>apartamentos</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider002.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>bravtevilla</p>
          <p>casas</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider003.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>business Center Dorado</p>
          <p>oficinas</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider004.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>balcones de la trinidad</p>
          <p>apartamentos</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider005.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>gratamira 131</p>
          <p>apartamentos</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider006.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>torre olaya plaza</p>
          <p>apartamentos y plaza comercial</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider007.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>torre olaya plaza</p>
          <p>locales comerciales</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider008.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>plaza castilla</p>
          <p>apartamentos</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="slider-project">
        <img src="images/home-slider009.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="img-data">
          <p>sauses del country</p>
          <p>apartamentos</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the code I have is jQuery:

```
var slider = $('#home-slider-c'),
  next = $('.slider-nav .next'),
  prev = $('.slider-nav .prev');

$('#home-slider-c section:last-child').insertBefore('#home-slider-c section:first-child');
  slider.css('margin-left', '-100%');

  var n = 0;
  function getNext() {
    var e = n === $('.slider-project').length - 1 ? 0 : n + 1;
    $(".current").html(e + 1);
    n++;
    console.log(e);
    slider.animate({
      marginLeft: '-200%'
    }, 700, function() {
      $('#home-slider-c section:first-child').insertAfter('#home-slider-c section:last-child');
      slider.css('margin-left', '-100%');
    });
    // $(".current").html(e++);
  }
  var n = 0;
  function getPrev() {
    var e = n <= 0 ? $('.slider-project').length - 1 : n - 1;
    $(".current").html(e + 1);
    n--;
    console.log(e);
    slider.animate({
      marginLeft: 0
    }, 700, function() {
      $('#home-slider-c section:last-child').insertBefore('#home-slider-c section:first-child');
      slider.css('margin-left', '-100%');
    });
  }

next.on('click', getNext);
prev.on('click', getPrev);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this single counter e initialized to 1

```
 ....
 var e= 1;
 function getNext() {
    e=  e<$('.slider-project').length?e:0;
    e++;
    $(".current").html(e);
    // n++;
     console.log(e);
  ....
   }
function getPrev() {
   e=  e<=1?$('.slider-project').length+1:e;
   e--;
   $(".current").html(e);
   //  n--;
    console.log(e);
     ....
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Reminder Operator `%` Here you go:

```js
var tot = 6,    // Let's say we have 6 slides.
    c = 0;      // Dummy counter

$("#prev, #next").on("click", function(){
  
  // Increment or decrement counter depending on button ID
  c = this.id==="next" ? ++c : --c; 
  
  // OK almost there, now let's loop our counter to prevent exceeding <0 or >5 
  // >5 since index 5 is the 6th slide (tot-1).
  // If counter went less than 0 (prev button) than set it to tot-1
  // For all other cases use modulo % which will reset it to 0 automagically.
  c = c<0 ? tot-1 : c%tot;
  
  $("#test").text(c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id=prev>&laquo;</button>
<span id=test>0</span>
<button id=next>&raquo;</button>
```

The above can be written using a bigger `if else` logic, but if it's all clear than you can simply use this snippet and drop it into any current or future gallery you build:

```
// Logic to loop counter on prev / next click:
c = (this.id==="next" ? ++c : --c) < 0 ? tot-1 : c%tot;
```